# What is the name of the postition with the leg retracted (in japanese)?

Tags: karate, kicking, stance, terminology, japanese

Recently my karate teacher told us to find out the name of the position (or it might have been the *act* of retracting your leg after a kick - I can't remember) when you retract your leg after a kick. For example after a front kick (*mae geri*), you kick and then you retract your leg before going back in your stance. He gave us a hint : it starts with the letter **w** (in japanese)

Comment: The closest I can find is waza - "technique" - http://www.traditional-karate.com/karate/terms.html#Kerikata

Comment: I found that, but I don't think that's it.

Comment: I don't either, that's just about the only non technique W I could find. and nothing specifically about retraction/recovery.

Comment: Either way, thank you, this list of terms might be useful.

Comment: You might get an answer on [japanse.se](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)…

Answer (score 4):

[引き](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8F) /hiki/ meaning "pulling; drawing back" might fit, though it doesn't begin with *w*.

Answer (score 1):

I know in some schools they teach that the transitional stance before/after a kick is neko-dachi (the cat stance). I remember being quized on this very question in class once and that was the answer.